How to run GUI in Docker in window
How i can build and run the GUI or display the output on the same screen while running the docker image in Window PC.
I had tried build and use two different server like Xming or VcXsrv to run but getting the same error.
I had tried using the X host in linux it worked but in window I'm getting the issue.
Help me out to get it out of this.

If you're already running an X server, and it's a Linux container, then Can you run GUI applications in a Linux Docker container? is the canonical question.  It'll be much easier if you can run a native application without a container, though: this setup already needs two non-standard software installations on Windows and the trickiness of the setup will be pushed on to your end users.
